# Sending email from c# code

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send an e-mail from my C# code.Here is an example

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add("milos90zr@gmail.com");
            message.Subject = "Registration";
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("milos90zr@hotmail.com");
            message.Body = "OK";
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Send(message);
```

But my code breaks and here is the error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. hn4sm3874638bkc.2 - gsmtp
```

Comment: You need authentication using the `NetworkCredential` object.

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn on encryption.

Put this line somewhere before `smtp.Send()`

```
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```